# Eclipse Java Photon not reading the code I typed

Tags: java, eclipse

Last night I turned my computer off like I usually do. Then I came home today and turned on my computer, opened eclipse, and then boom all of my code is underlined red. I have no idea why either. For example, it says "The import java.util cannot be resolved" for import java.util.Scanner. I am totally lost. My laptop too is saying that "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: ". I even reinstalled JDK on my laptop but that didn't do anything. I really don't understand how it would stop working on my laptop and then onto my desktop. I am so confused.

Comment: Please check the JRE configuration from Project | Properties | Build Path - Libraries Tab.

Comment: (It is advisable to exit Eclipse cleanly before shutting off your computer ...)

Comment: Workspace settings are *only* saved when you exit Eclipse, so if you turn off your computer with exiting Eclipse or shutting down the OS, those settings are lost, so you need to reconfigure it all again. Also, right-click the project and select "refresh", and also do a clean build (pull-down menu item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > . My laptop too is saying that "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: ".

Install JDK on your laptop. And you have already done it.

2. > "The import java.util cannot be resolved" for import java.util.Scanner. "

Configure your build path on eclipse:

- Right click on you Eclipse project.
- Choose Build path/Configure build path.
- Choose Java build path on the left panel, you can check in Libraries tab to make sure that your project is linked to JDK.